# keysSortedByValueUsingComparator not giving a properly ordered array

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary whose keys consist of `NSNumber`s. I am using `keysSortedByValueUsingComparator` as follows:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [self.platformDict  keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [(NSNumber*)obj2 compare:(NSNumber*)obj1];
    }];
```

However here is the result I get:

```
(lldb) po sortedKeys
(NSArray *) $1 = 0x0704bd20 <__NSArrayI 0x704bd20>(
100000,
250000,
1000000,
500000,
3000000,
2000000,
5000000,
10000000
)
```

Which is out of order. Is this a bug with the method implementation or is there another issue here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps you're misunderstanding what the `keysSortedByValue:...` method does. It does *not* sort the keys (for that you would just sort the array returned by `allKeys`), instead it sorts the values and then applies their order to the keys.

So let's say you have the following dictionary:

```
{"Orange": 1, "Apple": 3, "Peach": 2}
```

The result would be:

```
"Orange", "Peach", "Apple"
```

because that corresponds to the sorted order of the values (1, 2, 3).

Answer (score 4):

You can just use sortedArrayUsingSelector:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[self.PlatformDict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the internal of the block with the following. This will tell you if it is a problem with the compare method or something else.

```
 if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
 }

 if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
 }
 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
```